# Can't save my RC file changes with GIT

Tags: git, mfc, tortoisegit, visual-studio-2017

I am pulling my hair out now.

I got this MFC project and it has a GIT repository (I use TortoiseGit).

If I make changes to my RC file in resource editor my changes will not get saved. It refuses.

This has happened a lot.

I have tried switching off auto recover in IDE settings.

I can't resolve this. :(

Tried :

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2839032

### UPDATE

Here is some further clarification about what is happening. I make changes to the resources in some way ....

1/ *Sometimes* when I go to double-click the resource branch in the IDE it says that the RC file is already open in another editor. It isn't. There is no other editor open, and their is no resource.h file open. When this happens I have to restart the project.

2/ When I go to build the project it says it can't save the RC file. When this happens I have to try and close the project and eventually, when I say yes to the "save changes to open files" it saves them and shuts down the project. Then I open again.

I also file several temporary resource files in the solution folder which I then just delete.

Comment: Won't get saved to disk, or to git?

Comment: To disk. I can't build my app.

Comment: To get out of the problem I have to abort the project, restart the computer, add the changes and build. But then very quickly the issue starts again. It is only since I started trying to use source control.

Comment: If you can't even save the file in resource editor, I don't see what this has to do with git.

Comment: Because I have read about it somewhere. Either way I have this recurring issue.

Comment: Does it work, if you make changes to the rc file with notepad?

Comment: @MichaelWalz No. Eventually what I find I can do is go to close the project and let is flag to save. Eventually it allows it. But it is annoying. Making resource editing harder now.

Comment: Are you sure it's related to git ? I'm using git (though not TortoiseGit) and I maintain several MFC projects and I never had any problem saving rc files.

Comment: @MichaelWalz, well, in that case, it might not be the root cause. But I still have the issue. <scratches head>